# $.each + json + click event + object output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I am REALLY hoping this doesn't have a simple explanation, since that would mean lots and lots of lost hours (although that won't change the fact that they're lost anyway.) Some help or a kick in the right direction would be a deadline saver. Please.

I am trying to achieve the following;

1.) create a list of links that is populated by the JSON file (works)
2.) bind a click event on each li or a that passes a category object along to a builder function (think this works)
3.) user that object to do some cool stuff

However, there is some weird repetition going on once I reach my builder function.

Consider my JSON file called categories.json:

```
[
{   
    "category": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Title 1",
            "values": [
                {
                    "eg": [
                        {
                            "number": "12000000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{   
    "category": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Title 2",
            "values": [
                {
                    "eg": [
                        {
                            "number": "37000000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{   
    "category": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Title 3",
            "values": [
                {
                    "eg": [
                        {
                            "number": "37000000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

And then where I am definitely going wrong, my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Get the necessary data from the JSON file
$.getJSON("categories.json", function(categories) {
    $.each(categories, function(c, category) {
        var link = new Nav(category.category);
    });
});

Nav = function(groups){
    $.each(groups, function(g, group) {
        //console.log(group);
        $('#categories').append('<li><a href="#">'+group.title+'</a></li>').data(group);
        $('#categories li a').on('click', function(){
            var builder = new Builder(group);
        });
        //$('#categories').append('<li><a href="#">'+this.title+'</a></li>');
        //$('#categories').append(
        //    $("<li/>", { id: links.id, text: links.title}).data('navver', links)
        //);

    });
};

Builder = function(builder){
    console.log(builder);
};

});
```

As you can see there are some other "tries" commented out. So when I click on the FIRST generated link, I get this output in console.log:

```
Object { id="1", title="Title 1", values=[1]}
Object { id="2", title="Title 2", values=[1]}
Object { id="3", title="Title 3", values=[1]}
```

Which is the entire array, and not just the first item. When I click on the second link:

```
Object { id="2", title="Title 2", values=[1]}
Object { id="3", title="Title 3", values=[1]}
```

And when I click on the third link:

```
Object { id="3", title="Title 3", values=[1]}
```

What I would like to happen, is that the correct object gets returned when I click on the corresponding link.

Are there any smart chaps out there with some time on their hands that would please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh... there it is. Its because you're binding the event multiple times to all li's over and over.

[***Check out this fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Qszr6/1/)

My only change was this. So the click event gets bound to the newly appended li instead of all of them.

```
 $('#categories li:last a').on('click', function(){
            var builder = new Builder(group);
        });
```

Comment: Doh :/ I knew it was going to be something stupid. Thank you very much. Legend.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the following lines where you are binding the events:

```
    $('#categories').append('<li><a href="#">'+group.title+'</a></li>').data(group);
    $('#categories li a').on('click', function(){
        var builder = new Builder(group);
    });
```

With the following:

```
        var li = $('<li><a href="#">' + group.title + '</a></li>');
        $('#categories').append(li ).data(group);
        li.find('a').on('click', function() {
            var builder = new Builder(group);
        });
```

The problem is you are using the selector `$('#categories li a')` each time after you add one of those elements so the first `<a>` added gets the handler binded three times, the second two and the third one time.

You can find a modified version of your code, working with this modification, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9T594/2/).

Comment: Works like a charm as well - thank you for taking the time. I appreciate it.